# OpenGL error 1282 when returning struct with uint array member

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, opengl-4

I get OpenGL error 1282 when I try to run fragment shader with a function that returns struct with uint array initialized from function argument and integer literal.

When I run my program with the fragment shader below everything works and the result I get is white screen

```
#version 460

uniform uint param;
out vec4 color;

struct A {
    uint content[2];
};

A createA1(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](data, data) ); }
A createA2(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](data, 0   ) ); }
A createA3(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](data, 0u  ) ); }
A createA4(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](0   , 0   ) ); }

void main() {
    const uint o = param;

    const A a0 = A( uint[2](o, 0) );
    const A a1 = createA1(o);
    //const A a2 = createA2(o);
    const A a3 = createA3(o);
    const A a4 = createA4(o);
    
    color = vec4(1);
}
```

But when I uncomment the line with a2 I get OpenGL error 1282.

I tried glslangValidator on the code and it printed no errors. What is also strange for me is that *a4* that also uses the same literal zero does not produce any errors. And it seems to matter that *o* is initialized from the uniform because if I replace the uniform with some literal value the error goes away.

If it is actually a bug (which it seems to me) and not some glsl peculiarity, the program I tested the shader in was run on Windows with Nvidia graphics card.

UPD: So I didn't clarify the problem enough: the shader is compiled without errors but the program doesn't link and I get 1282. I called `glCreateProgram`, for both fragment and vertex shaders I called `glCreateShader`, `glShaderSource`, `glCompileShader`, `glGetShaderiv` with `GL_COMPILE_STATUS`, printed the *param* value (for both shaders the result was 1), `glAttachShader` and `glLinkProgram` afterwards with **no** other calls in between.
When I checked `GL_LINK_STATUS` though the result was 0.

When I printed information log for the program object it said

```
Fragment info
-------------
0(11) : error C7011: implicit cast from "int" to "uint"
```

which was expected because *a3* was the solution to the problem. But I don't understand two things:

1. why *a0* works and *a2* doesn't since the same implicit cast is present in both of them, and why the error disappears if I assign some integer constant instead of uniform value to *o*.
2. why the shader status after compilation is 1 while program object says there is an error in the shader.

And for completeness here is the entire program:

```
#include <GLEW/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include<iostream>

void check_(int line) {
    GLenum error;
    while ((error = glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR) { 
        std::cout << "Error on line " << line << ": " << error << std::endl;
    }
}
#define check() check_(__LINE__)
                            
int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) return -1;
    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(50, 50, "", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) return (glfwTerminate(), -1);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (err != GLEW_OK) {
        std::cout << "GLEW error: %s\n" << glewGetErrorString(err) << '\n';     
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    
    GLuint prog = glCreateProgram();
    
    GLuint shader_vert = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint shader_frag = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    char const *source_vert = R"(#version 460
        void main() {
            const vec2 verts[] = {vec2(-1),vec2(1, -1),vec2(-1, 1),vec2(1)};
            gl_Position = vec4( verts[gl_VertexID], 0, 1 );
        }
    )";
    char const *source_frag = R"(#version 460
        
        uniform uint param;
        out vec4 color;
        
        struct A {
            uint content[2];
        };
        
        A createA1(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](data, data) ); }
        A createA2(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](data, 0   ) ); }
        A createA3(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](data, 0u  ) ); }
        A createA4(const uint data) { return A( uint[2](0   , 0   ) ); }
        
        void main() {
            const uint o = param;
            
            const A a0 = A( uint[2](o, 0) );
            const A a1 = createA1(o);
            const A a2 = createA2(o);
            const A a3 = createA3(o);
            const A a4 = createA4(o);
            
            color = vec4(1);
        }
    )";
    
    glShaderSource(shader_vert, 1, &source_vert, nullptr); 
    glCompileShader(shader_vert);
    glShaderSource(shader_frag, 1, &source_frag, nullptr); 
    glCompileShader(shader_frag);
    
    GLint result_vert;
    glGetShaderiv(shader_vert, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result_vert);
    std::cout << "result_vert: " << result_vert << '\n';
    GLint result_frag;
    glGetShaderiv(shader_frag, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result_frag);
    std::cout << "result_frag: " << result_frag << '\n';
    //check(); //additional checks were ommited after the problem was found
    
    glAttachShader(prog, shader_vert);
    glAttachShader(prog, shader_frag);
    
    glLinkProgram(prog);
    GLint progStatus;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &progStatus);
    std::cout << "Program status: " << progStatus << '\n';
    {
        int length;
        glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        GLchar *msg = new GLchar[length + 1];
        msg[0] = '\0';
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, length, &length, msg);
        std::cout << "Program error:\n" << msg;
        delete[] msg;
    }
    
    glValidateProgram(prog);
    GLint progValidate;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &progValidate);
    std::cout << "Program valid: " << progValidate << '\n';
    //check();
    
    glUseProgram(prog);
    check();
    
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1282 is the catch-all invalid operation error for OpenGL, it says nothing.

Enable the debugging layers and check the result of your shader compilation and (since it's probably failing) the resulting info log to see the actual problem.

> If it is actually a bug (which it seems to me)

No, you did not happen to be the only person in this world to find a bug in compiling a shader. Check your error returns, enable the debug layers and fix your code.